# How to loop through specific data frames based on a List and add them all in a rbind function using R?

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I have 5 dataframes all with the same heading and columns

```
df1,df2,df3,df4,df5
```

I created a list based on the dataframe names

```
List<-c("df1","df2","df3","df4",d"f5")
```

I want to create an rbind looping the df's based off the list. i tried this

```
ALL_dfs<-lapply(List,rbind)
```

but this doesn't read it as a combined dataframe by rbind function.

Comment: You can `rbind`multiple data frames directly.  `bigdf <- rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)`

Comment: The example i use shows 5, but in reality i have way more than that and would just like a quick loop statement that would do exactly that, but not having me to write each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward option is this:

```
do.call(rbind, mget(List))
```

`?mget`

> Search by name for an object (get) or zero or more objects (mget).

The other option, if possible, is to store your data.frames in a list when you create them. Not always an option, but may be possible with some planning

Comment: this is it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With map_df from purrr.

```
library(purrr)
all_dfs <- map_dfr(.x = List, .f = bindr)
```

Comment: I got Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'bind_rows' not found

Comment: it needs to be `dplyr::bind_rows`